# InRecovery SQL Server Database Mode

Tags: sql, sql-server

there is a database that work with it from before to know. know this database (ms sql database) was in InRecovery Mode. in this mode, when i can see it in SQL Server Management Studio, but i cant do anything else. this mean that i can not see tables, i can not see data for each table, ... . in abstract, the plus button beside of database name does not exist. and you can guess other things that i can not do. this problem is from where? and how i can solve this. (note: i have not any backups for this database)

Comment: Check your SQL Server error logs for indications of why it is in recovery mode in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to wait for it to come out of recovery mode.  Basically, something bad happened to it and SQL is trying to recover from that.  If it can't recover, and you have no backups, then you are pretty much out of luck.

Comment: this problem was happened two or three days ago. and at know this problem is in it's location!

Comment: @Pezhman There are a lot of things that can cause it to take a long time.  If you continue to have problems with it you might want to ask a question on http://dba.stackexchange.com.